# cURL to localhost gets dropped by iptables

Tags: linux, networking, debian, iptables, curl

I'm trying to use cURL on the shell to connect to localhost. I'm using `curl http://localhost:80` to connect. Unfortunately, it's being blocked by iptables. Here's the error in the iptables log for why:

```
IPTables-Dropped: IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=58617 WINDOW=32768 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0
```

And here's the iptables:

```
iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 314 packets, 19725 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
30731 4342K ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
  255 31984 ACCEPT     all  --  eth1   any     anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    6   360 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
  207 28142 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     localhost.localdomain  anywhere             tcp dpt:6379
  173  9634 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     localhost.localdomain  anywhere             tcp spt:6379

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 31748 packets, 2974K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

I think I've narrowed it down to the fact that cURL appears to be using a destination port that's not 80. It changes too, every time I do a new cURL request. You can see this in the log entry: `SPT=80 DPT=58617`. Solving this (I imagine) should solve the issue.

Some notes:

- Running Debian Wheezy
- The web server is nginx
- Connections from localhost to the local Redis server work just fine.

**Update:** Adding the following rule `-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT` fixes the issue. Is there a security concern for allowing connections based on the source port and not the destination port?

Comment: Please post the _complete_ firewall rules (you must use `-v`). As it is currently it is impossible to determine the state of your firewall because without `-v` parts of the rules are not displayed.

Comment: I updated the iptables rules

Comment: OK, that's a rather messy firewall. Did you find it on the Internet somewhere?

Comment: Bits and pieces, yes. Can you elaborate on how it should be cleaned up?

Comment: cURL is connecting to port 80 as it should. The packet that gets dropped is the answer of the web server, having source port 80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `RELATED,ESTABLISHED` rules only for interfaces eth0 and eth1, therefore the answer of the web server to the connection request of cURL will be dropped by iptables because it is not accepted by any rule. Changing the `RELATED,ESTABLISHED` rule so it applies to all interfaces should solve the problem.

Do not use rules accepting traffic *from* specific source ports unless you need them for a very specific reason: having a rule accepting all traffic *from* port 80 would mean that anybody could then connect to any of your services if he/she can open the connection *from* port 80 (trivial for any attacker).